# Conversion between 2 template types

Tags: c++, class, templates, initialization, type-conversion

I've got this piece of code for a class (this is a snippet):

```
template<typename T>
class Pos2 {
public:
    T x, y;

    Pos2() : x(0), y(0) {};
    Pos2(T xy) : x(xy), y(xy) {};
    Pos2(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {};

};
```

Now, I've also got 2 typedefs for it:

```
typedef Pos2<pos_scalar> Pos;
typedef Pos2<size_scalar> Size;
```

Everything works as expected, but when I do this:

```
Pos p(5.5, 6.5);
Size s(3, 8);
p = s;
```

I get this error:

```
error: conversion from ‘Size {aka Pos2<short int>}’ to non-scalar type ‘Pos’ requested
```

It makes sense, but I'd like to know how to fix it =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor

```
template <typename Type2> Pos2(const Pos2<Type2> &other)
{ x = other.x; y = other.y; }
```

Comment: What is `Type2`? Did you mean `typename Type2`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an assignment operator for assignment from type `Size` to type `Pos`, because these are not the same type and therefore there is no default assignment operator between the two.

I guess you want to use a template here, so any instantiation of `Pos2` can be used to assign to another instantiation. For example like so:

```
template<typename T>
class Pos2 {
public:
    T x, y;

    Pos2() : x(0), y(0) {};
    Pos2(T xy) : x(xy), y(xy) {};
    Pos2(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {};

    template<typename FromT>
    Pos2<T>& operator=(const Pos2<FromT>& from) {
        x = from.x;
        y = from.y;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

You should do the same with the copy constructor (not shown here), because it might likely happen that you want to copy construct in the same scheme at some point.

This does only work if the assignment between type `T` and `FromT`, that is `pos_scalar` and `size_scalar` is possible. If not try to add correct explicit conversions and/or template specializations for the assignment operator.

Also if any of the members of `Pos2` are private/protected you will need to `friend` the assignment operator or provide adequate getters.